# Ubuntu 16.04 install failed

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I'm installing Ubuntu 16.04 on a VM and it fails towards the end of installing the Base System. I've attached a screenshot of the error messages below. Any idea why this might be?

[image]

Comment: So see the log, or press Right Ctl+F4 to get to the console for details.

Comment: Hi Pilot. I'm a total noob, how do I view the log? I tried pressing right ctrl and F4 but it didn't do anything. Thanks

Comment: Found it! Looks like something to do with my web proxy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I had forgotten to put the "http://" in front of my proxy URL. Thanks for quickly pointing me in the right direction :)